# add functions to javascript / JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".box").each(function(){
    $(this).distance_left = function() {
        return $(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().offset().left;
    }
    $(this).distance_top = function() {
        return $(this).offset().top - $(this).parent().offset().top;
    }

});
```

When I call distance_left or distance_top on a .box object, I simply get a `box.distance_left is not a function`. Why?

Comment: because each time you create a jQuery wrapper a new object is created... you can use a plugin model for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sLm38zz9/1/

Comment: Please elaborate with example also.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend the prototype:

```
$.fn.distance_left = function() { return -1; };
```

and then you can use it on all jQuery objects:

```
$('#myId').distance_left(); // -1
```

Anyway for your particually case you can use

```
$(this).position().left;
$(this).position().top;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because each time you create a jQuery wrapper a new object is returned, so even though you assign the properties to a wrapper instance it won't be available in another one.

One easy way to test it is compare `$(this) == $(this)` which will return false.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yvv2z9e3/1/)

The solution here is to use a plugin model as given below.

```
$.fn.distance_left = function () {
    return $(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().offset().left;
}
$.fn.distance_top = function () {
    return $(this).offset().top - $(this).parent().offset().top;
}
```

Comment: `return` twice in `distance_left`!! needed or typo??

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
var that = $(this);
```

Because `this` frequently changes when changing scope by using a new function, you cannot simply access the original value by using it. Aliasing it to `that` allows you still to access the original value of `this`.

So your code would be

```
$(".box").each(function(){
    var that=$(this);
    that.distance_left = function() {
        return that.offset().left - that.parent().offset().left;
    }
    that.distance_top = function() {
        return that.offset().top - that.parent().offset().top;
    }

});
```

Comment: The case is not about `this` but about recreating of jQuery objects.